# Unity DIC missing System.Runtime reference

Tags: .net, unity-container, .net-4.5, .net-4.5.2

I've a plain new .NET 4.5 class library project.

To this project I add the current Unity NuGet package and add the dependency attribute to one property.

Then I got the following compile error:

> Error 9   The type 'System.Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

But there is the correct DLL in the Facades directory:

> %program files%\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Facades\System.Runtime.dll

By adding the Reference manually the error disappears.

But for me that smells.

Also the assembly doesn't appear to be in the GAC.

When I build a custom attribute and annotate a class with it, I don't get this error.
So it should be related to Unity DIC?

Does someone know what's the reason behind this? And is there a better way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this is an error when 4.5.2 comes only whith visual studio

reinstalling the .net 4.5.2 sdk helped

Comment: You mean that If I don't add this reference, it should work fine in the build server ?

Comment: It worked for me as well. Download link : 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42637

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2971005/